# How to write a C# / Roslyn analyser to match a ReactiveUI property?

Tags: c#, roslyn-code-analysis

If I have the following idiomatic [ReactiveUI](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI) property declaration

```
private int _Foo;
public int Foo { 
   get { return _Foo; } 
   set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _Foo, value); } 
}
```

where **Foo** can be any name whatsover. What would be the diagonostic matcher for this as part of a roslyn analyser?

I allready have the codefix written I want but currently I allow it to be applied to any property. I want to tighten it so it only applies to properties with exactly the above shape.

My current attempt falls back to using Regex to strip the trivia then doing a ToString and then matching exactly the string output. I'm not sure if there is a better way to do this.

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics;

namespace ReactiveUI.Fody.CodeFix
{
[DiagnosticAnalyzer(LanguageNames.CSharp)]
public class ReactiveUIFodyCodeFixAnalyzer : DiagnosticAnalyzer
{
    public const string DiagnosticId = "ReactiveUIFodyCodeFix";

    // You can change these strings in the Resources.resx file. If you do not want your analyzer to be localize-able, you can use regular strings for Title and MessageFormat.
    // See https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/docs/analyzers/Localizing%20Analyzers.md for more on localization
    private static readonly string Title = "ReactiveUI.Fody CodeFix";
    private static readonly string MessageFormat = "The property {0} can be simplified using ReactiveUI.Fody";

    private static readonly string Description =
    "This code fix changes boiler plate INPC property declaration to simple ones using a fody attribute";

    private const string Category = "Properties";

    private static readonly DiagnosticDescriptor Rule = new DiagnosticDescriptor(DiagnosticId, Title, MessageFormat, Category, DiagnosticSeverity.Warning, isEnabledByDefault: true, description: Description);

    public override ImmutableArray<DiagnosticDescriptor> SupportedDiagnostics => ImmutableArray.Create(Rule);

    public override void Initialize(AnalysisContext context)
    {
    context.RegisterSymbolAction(ChangePropertyModifierRule, SymbolKind.Property);
    }


    private static void ChangePropertyModifierRule(SymbolAnalysisContext context)
    {
    var propertySymbol = context.Symbol as IPropertySymbol;


    // Check if the ReactiveAttribute is already applied and if so 
    // skip it.
    var attributes = propertySymbol.GetAttributes();
    if (attributes.Any(attr => attr.AttributeClass.Name == "Reactive"))
        return;

    if (propertySymbol != null)
    {
        var property = propertySymbol.DeclaringSyntaxReferences[0].GetSyntax() as PropertyDeclarationSyntax;
        Debug.Assert(property != null, "property != null");
        var getter = property.AccessorList?.Accessors.FirstOrDefault(x => x.IsKind(SyntaxKind.GetAccessorDeclaration));
        var setter = property.AccessorList?.Accessors.FirstOrDefault(x => x.IsKind(SyntaxKind.SetAccessorDeclaration));

        if (setter?.Body == null)
        return;
        if (getter?.Body == null)
        return;

        if (setter.Body.Statements.Count != 1)
        return;

        var statement = setter.Body;
        if (!statement.ToString().Contains("RaiseAndSetIfChanged"))
        return;
        var idiom = $"{{this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref_{propertySymbol.Name},value);}}";
        var noWhiteSpace = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(statement.ToString(), @"\s+", "");

        if (idiom != noWhiteSpace)
        return;

        // Add "contextual" menu to change property modifiers.
        var diagnostic = Diagnostic.Create(Rule, propertySymbol.Locations[0], propertySymbol.Name);

        context.ReportDiagnostic(diagnostic);
    }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Should this be recognised too: `RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref this._Foo, value);` ? What if the underlying field for property `X` is called `x` (or even `_y`) ?

Comment: True but the idomatic way is from http://reactiveui.net/.  I have an open pull request on ReactiveUI.Fody at https://github.com/kswoll/ReactiveUI.Fody/pull/27. If you would like to assist with a more flexibile analyser it would be appreciated.

Comment: The thing is: what you have now is working. You are asking us for a *better* way, but you'll have to tell us what that means. Better how? Producing the exact same matches, but in a more efficient way? Or be "better" (and therefor different) at what it matches? Give us examples, and ask a concrete question.

Comment: I had no solution when I asked the question. But now I do I think it still would be better not to be using a string match over the entire statement. So to be precise a "better" way would be to perform the match by pattern matching over the syntax tree in some method. But then again I might be wrong and this might be the best way to do something like this. It is my first analyser and at the time of writing the question I was not able to figure out how to get any solution.

Comment: Note that I use a regex to collapse all the whitespace ( remove all the trivia ) and then compare that to an expected value. I'd like to see the equivalent code that strips all the trivia from the syntax tree and then compares to an expected syntax tree without collapsing an entire syntax tree to a string.

Comment: If you want to pattern match the syntax tree, which certainly sounds like a good idea, you first need to know what it looks like. The easiest way to find out is using the [Syntax Visualizer](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Syntax%20Visualizer). Alternatively, write your unit test and debug it to look at its syntax tree. Then you can test that the getter is an AccessorDeclarationSyntax with a BlockSyntax that contains a ReturnStatementSyntax whose Expression is a SimpleNameSyntax, and so on. The setter would then contain an InvocationExpressionSyntax and so on.